# How to create a WordPress blog with user Registration?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website but I am unable to make a website where Users can register and Post Articles on the Blog.
Note,
I have used all kinds of Plugins but they all use the default WordPress Admin Page and New Post Page.
I want everything Custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some links which can help you creating users and post by custom. in these function send parameters according to your requirements. Hope this will helps you.

[Create Post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

[Create wp user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)